# How to get rid of this Eclipse warning?

Tags: c++, eclipse, warnings

I have a function like the one below in Eclipse. However, because there is no return outside the while loop, Eclipse assumes that I may have a logical error (probably it can't see that the condition of the while is always true.

Switching to a do-while won't help. Is there any way that I can get rid of this warning programmatically, i.e., not by modifying settings of Eclipse IDE.

```
int foo(...)
{
    while (1) {
        ...

        if(...)
            return -1;

        ...

        if(...)
            return 0;
    }
}
```

I compiled the same function in the terminal and had no warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `return` statement before the closing brace, even if you expect it never to be reached.
I have had a similar warning from Visual Studio 2010, and adding an apparently extraneous `return` fixed the problem.

Comment: No, this will not solve the problem. Maybe Eclipse assumes that I may not entering the while loop at all. Or are you referring to the ending brace of the function? (If so, one could see I have already mention that in my question :) ).

Comment: I did mean the closing brace of the function. I did see that you stated there is no `return` outside the `while loop`; and semantically, it does not appear necessary. But it is not uncommon for compilers to be a little over-zealous (or not quite thorough) in checking for `return` statements. Adding such a statement would serve only to get the compiler to stop complaining about what it thinks is a problem.

Comment: Adding an `assert(false);` before the return statement would be good programming practice, too.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the fix, use a return value variable:

```
int foo(...)
{
  int return_value = 0;
  while (true)
  {
    //...
    if (...)
    {
      return_value = -1;
      break; // out of the while loop
    }
    if (...)
    {
       return_value = 0;
       break;
    }
  }
  return return_value;
}
```

One entry point, one exit point.